# AWS S3 Javascript SDK - how to list objects after specific lastModified date?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

We need to list a large number of objects from S3, but we only wish to extract objects modified after dateX.

It seems from the official S3 REST API that this type of filtered request is possible, and it should be e.g. via the AWS S3 CLI. However, for our purposes we need to be able to do this as part of a front-end web application - hence I'm trying to solve this in Javascript.

Anyone who has succeeded in achieving something like this? My assumption would be that it requires a Javascript based implementation of the S3 REST API, but I've not been able to find anything on this.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thorough review I found that this is seemingly not possible to achieve via the Javascript SDK.